# Почему при запуске html документа пропадают фотографии?

Tags: html

Когда я запускаю сайт через live-server мой сайт полноценно функционирует, но стоит его открыть через html документ вылезают ошибки в консоли(Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) и исчезают картинки. Все пути в файле правильные.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в браузере стоит расширение, которое убирает картинки с ключевым словом: например adBlock, который реагирует на классы, начинающиеся с `ad-` и подобное. В общем, проблема в расширении браузера